# TFS Alert if change was made by users in a certain TFS Group / AD Group?

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

I am trying to set up an alert that will send me an email when someone who has Work Item Only View access creates/changes a Work Item.

I can create a query which returns me a list of Work Items which were created by WIOV users, by using 'Created By (In Group) "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Work Item Only View Users"', or alternatively the AD Group which I created which controls which users have WIOV access.

But there does not appear to be an "In Group" operator in the Alerts Explorer.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Aside from having a separate clause for every WIOV user.

Comment: See comments in accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check in an alert rule if a given user is a member of a group, so you won't be able to do that this way.

Maybe the fallback would be to ask to your wiov users to create the work items and not assigning them to someone (let the assigned to field empty), then you could be able to create the alert that triggers when such Work Item is create.

Note: you may have to change the definition of the Work Item to allow an empty "Assigned to" (depending of the Process Template you use).

Comment: In our current process for normal TFS users, we regularly create Items which have no initial Assigned To user.

Comment: Then try to use something else like a custom field the wiov user have to set, or a specific area path, something discriminant

Comment: Hmm you might be on to something. I could edit the work item template to set a custom field to true when the work item is created by a user in a certain group.  I'll give it a go next week. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, you'll find a way, it won't be the best ideal one, but it'll work at a certain level.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but you could do this a different way.  Create a new project team in TFS and add your specific users/AD groups to that project team.  Then, set the alert just for that specific project team.